# iOS alternative for Androids <include> tag?

Tags: ios, reusability

How am I supposed to reuse views in iOS?

For example, I have a view that returns as a `CollectionViewCell`, inside of a `UITableViewCell` and on a specific spot in a `UIViewController`.

What is the recommended way to deal with this?

Do I make a xib and add a holder view everywhere I need it?

But, then to react to size changes, I need to add constraints in code, which seems to be too much hassle just for a simple inclusion of a xib.

Is there a feature in Xcode I can use?

Comment: You could just make a UIView.h and .m for that view (e.g. mySickCell.h and mySickCell.m) - File>new file> and then choose the specific sort of view you want to make.  Then import than and declare new views as being of that type.  Or is that not what you want?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I want to create a view in interface builder and then reuse that in multiple views.

Comment: Then yeah I agree w/ @Darko you should use a xib.  There is another way to do it where you just have these unconnected views floating around in a storyboard and you write code to "connect" or "reuse" them so to speak but it quickly becomes ugly and hard to organize, so for your scenario a xib is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `UICollectionViewCell` in a XIB. Then this cell is placed inside an `UICollectionView`. You can place this `UICollectionView` basically everywhere, also inside an `UITableViewCell`. As the `UICollectionView` can be auto-layout constraint in the Storyboard the size changes automatically. No need for programmatic constraints. When you want to reuse the `UICollectionViewCell` just put it inside another `UICollectionView` in another `UIViewController` or `UITableViewCell`.

Btw: to use this just as "reusing"-feature you can disable the scrolling in the `UICollectionView`.